# Is there a way to stack two tensorflow datasets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to stack two datasets objects in Tensorflow (rbind function in R). I have created one dataset A from tfRecord files and one dataset B from numpy arrays. Both have same variables. Do you know if there is a way to stack these two datasets to create a bigger one ? Or to create an iterrator that will randomly read data from this two sources ?

Thanks

Comment: Post the code from your attempt, with a specific error or problem. Too broad.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [`tf.data.Dataset.concatenate()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#concatenate) method is the closest analog of `tf.stack()` when working with datasets. If you have two datasets with the same structure (i.e. same types for each component, but possibly different shapes):

```py
dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10, 20)
dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(60, 70)
```

then you can concatenate them as follows:

```py
combined_dataset = dataset_1.concatenate(dataset_2)
```

Comment: Adding to mrry's answer, there's also https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave which allows you to merge datasets instead of concatenate datasets.

You can then `Dataset.shuffle()` to randomize a batch of interleaved records.

Comment: I don't think that `tf.data.Dataset.concatenate()` has any resemblance to `tf.stack()`. `concatenate()` uses an existing dimension, `stack()` creates a new one. This is exactly the same in `numpy`, compare `np.concatenate()` and `np.stack()`.

Comment: From my tensorboard profiling, it seems like concatenation happens every epoch. Is there a way to perform it only once when pre-processing?

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have two datasets which elements shape is respectively (bs,d0,d1) and (bs,d0',d1) and you want a new dataset which element shape is (bs,d0+d0',d1) you can do it using tf.Dataset.zip and then concatenating each element on the second axis, like in the example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.zeros((100,4,8))
b = tf.ones((100,1,8))

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
d1 = d1.batch(16,drop_remainder=True)      # elements shape (16,4,8)

d2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b)
d2 = d2.batch(16,drop_remainder=True)      # elements shape (16,1,8)

d = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1,d2))
d = d.map(lambda x,y:tf.concat([x,y],axis=-2)) # elements shape (16,4+1,8)

it = iter(d)
x = next(it)
print(x.shape)
print(x)
```

If you want instead to stack two datasets with the same elements shape (bs,d0,d1) into a new dataset with elements shape (bs,d0,d1,2) you can do it zipping the two datasets and then staking the elements

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.zeros((100,4,8))
b = tf.ones((100,4,8))

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
d1 = d1.batch(16,drop_remainder=True)      # elements shape (16,4,8)

d2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b)
d2 = d2.batch(16,drop_remainder=True)      # elements shape (16,4,8)

d = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1,d2))
d = d.map(lambda x,y:tf.stack([x,y],axis=-1)) # elements shape (16,4,8,2)

it = iter(d)
x = next(it)
print(x.shape)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

If by stacking you mean what `tf.stack()` and `np.stack()` do:

> Stacks a list of rank-`R` tensors into one rank-`(R+1)` tensor.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack

> Join a sequence of arrays along a new axis.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

then I believe the closest you can come with a `tf.data.Dataset` is `Dataset.zip()`:

```
@staticmethod
zip(datasets)
```

> Creates a `Dataset` by zipping together the given datasets.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#zip

This allows you to iterate through multiple datasets at the same time by iterating over the shared dimension of the original datasets, similarly to a `stack()`ed tensor or matrix.

You can then also use `.map(tf.stack)` or `.map(lambda *t: tf.stack(t, axis=-1))` to stack the tensors along new dimensions at the front or back, respectively,

If indeed you want to achieve what `tf.concat()` and `np.concatenate()` do, then you use `Dataset.concatenate()`.