# Concatenating two Dataset with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What should I do to concatenate these two datasets? the tf.stack and np.stack don't work properly.

```
<MapDataset shapes: ((200, 100), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int32)>
<MapDataset shapes: ((2000, 100), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int32)>
---------------
What I want is:
<MapDataset shapes: ((2200, 100), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int32)>
```

I have used the tf.data.experimental.save() to save those two datasets in a zip file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ev1zHJl7iXHoYaMF1UeqVExF3a36ZZmC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide generated input data?

Comment: I saved those two datasets through tf.data.experimental.save()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771502/is-there-a-way-to-stack-two-tensorflow-datasets):

The tf.data.Dataset.concatenate() method is the closest analog of tf.stack() when workind with datasets. If you have two datasets with the same structure (i.e. same types for each component, but possibly different shapes):

```
dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10, 20)
dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(60, 70)
```

...you can concatenate them as follows:

```
combined_dataset = dataset_1.concatenate(dataset_2)
```

Does this help?