# Using model.fit with different data generators

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using this code to train my CNN:

```
history = model.fit(
  x = train_gen1,
  epochs = epochs,
  validation_data = valid_gen,
  callbacks = noaug_callbacks,
  class_weight = class_weight
).history
```

where train_gen1 is made using ImageDataGenerator. But what if I want to use 2 different types of generator (let's call them train_gen1 and train_gen2) both feeding my training phase? How can I change my code in order to do so?
This is the way I generate:

```
aug_train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=0,
                                    height_shift_range=40,
                                    width_shift_range=40,
                                    zoom_range=0,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    vertical_flip=True, 
                                    fill_mode='reflect',
                                    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
                                   )
train_gen1 = aug_train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=training_dir,
                                                   target_size=(96,96),
                                                   color_mode='rgb',
                                                   classes=None, # can be set to labels
                                                   class_mode='categorical',
                                                   batch_size=512,
                                                   shuffle= False #set to false if need to compare images
                                                   )
```

Comment: You need to use functional API: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#manipulate-complex-graph-topologies

Comment: @Frightera honestly I don't understand how to use it in my code. I'll add more details about the generation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799434/8143158